# Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 2

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, sublimetext

So I have been trying to figure out how to add syntax highlighting for the name of `typedef`'s in c++ files, in sublime text.

For example, if I have `typedef long long integer;` I want `integer` to be highlighted (preferably the same color as the other types: `int`, `bool`, etc.). I went looked at the C.tmLanuage file, and tried to add the following regex code `^typedef.*?\s(\w+)\s*;` to `storage.type.c` (line 49), but it didn't work. If I add the word `string`, it will highlight all instances of the word string. I tried going in the C++.tmLanguage file, and adding the regex code to `storage.type.c++`, but it still did not work.

Does anybody know how to get `typedef`'s highlighted in sublime text?

Also, is there a way to get syntax highlighting for class name? Let's say I declare a `string` or `vector`, I would like either `string` or `vector` to be highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex would work (I believe) if you had something along the lines of `typedef foo;` To get the behavior you want, you will have to create a slightly more complex pattern entry in the tmLanguage file. As the language file is based on TextMates, you will want to have this as a reference (http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars). I would also recommend using [PlistJsonConverter](https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter) (working in JSON is easier for me than working in XML). You will probably need to define begin and end patterns (begin will probably be `typedef` end will probably be `;`). You can then apply whatever patterns you want to that group.

As for the class name highlighting, I would look to see what, if any scopes are being applied. If none are, you will have to come up with a regex to apply the scope to those. You can then add a color entry, or use a defined one from the color scheme.

**Edit:**

Actually they don't appear to be JSON. I see `()` rather than `[]`. JSON is pretty simple to understand. You can look for something more in depth, but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) is a good place to start. What you would probably be interested in are the things under the "Rule Keys" section. I did some searching (because I knew there were some better examples out there), and came across http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html . It goes over syntax definitions from scratch, but the most relevant section is probably http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#analyzing-patterns. I don't have a regex to find class names, so you would have to come up with one yourself. If you haven't already though, you may want to search around to see if someone else has implemented a language file in a way that works for you.

You will want to start with the built in tmLanguage file and convert that from a Plist to json. You can then edit that file and move it back.

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON, but are the language grammars in the link you gave me written in JSON? If so, are you saying that I write something similar to what is written in the links and then convert it using the converter? Should I then put the conversion in the .tmLanguage file? Also, class names do not have a regex, so how would go about creating a regex to apply a scope for those?

Comment: Extended my answer as it felt to long for a comment.